# How to delete multiple columns with grep (only first column)?

Tags: grep

I have a file like this (delimited by `\t`):

```
AAED1   Previous_symbol     PRXL2C
AARS    Previous_symbol     AARS1
ABP1    Previous_symbol     AOC1
ACN9    Previous_symbol     SDHAF3
ADCY3   Previous_symbol     ADCY8
AK3     Previous_symbol     AK4
AK8     Previous_symbol     AK3
```

I want to delete the rows that contain `AAED1` and `AK3` in the first column. In reality my file have thousand of lines and I want to delete hundred of rows. I have a file with the patterns I want to search for (this is an example):

```
AAED1
AK3
```

I tried this:

```
grep -wvf pattern.txt file.txt
```

Expected output:

```
AARS    Previous_symbol     AARS1
ABP1    Previous_symbol     AOC1
ACN9    Previous_symbol     SDHAF3
ADCY3   Previous_symbol     ADCY8
AK8     Previous_symbol     AK3
```

The result I obtained:

```
AARS    Previous_symbol     AARS1
ABP1    Previous_symbol     AOC1
ACN9    Previous_symbol     SDHAF3
ADCY3   Previous_symbol     ADCY8
```

The last row is also deleted because it contains `AK3` on the third column. Is there a way to only `grep` the first column?

Comment: Check this thread Swimming bird. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230782/delete-column-that-includes-a-specific-text

Comment: Are you confusing columns and rows/lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current set up, the file with patterns will search for any occurrence of those patterns in the lines and so the line:

```
AK8    Previous_symbol    AK3
```

will also match AK3

You need to add a start of line marker to the patterns to ensure that the patterns are anchored checked at the start of the lines only and so:

```
^AAED1
^AK3
```

If you cannot directly edit the file with patterns use the following:

```
grep -f <(sed 's/^/^/' file1) file
```

With file 1 as the file with the patterns and file as the file to search. We run a sed command to replace the start of every line in file1 with ^ and then redirect the result back into grep as the patterns to check.